# Angular using ng-repeat to show hide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am new to angular and trying to incorporate it within my application.

So far i have been able to set up a simple `ng-repeat-start/end` which is working as expected.

The issue i am facing is that when a column in my table below: {{country.detail}} contains a value greater than 0 (for example: "5 details available"), the following row (.countries-detail) should SHOW.

If {{country.detail}} contains a value equal to 0 (for example: "0 details available"), the following row (.countries-detail) should HIDE.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="country in countries" >
   <td data-show="#show-{{$index}}">{{country.name}}</td>
   <td>{{country.population}}</td>
   <td>{{country.detail}}</td>
   <td>{{country.currency}}</td>
   <td>{{country.gpd}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat-end class="countries-detail" ng-hide="showCountriesDetail">
   <td>
       <div id="show-{{$index}}">
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
       </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**MyController:**

```
app.controller("CountriesController", function($scope) {

    $scope.showCountriesDetail = true;

});
```

Should i be handling this logic in the **controller**, or in a **directive**?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the expression 'country.detail <= 5' for ng-hide?

Comment: @GruffBunny - where would i place that? Also, the string in country.detail contains "5 details available"

Comment: @OamPsy Gruff Bunny is saying to put the inequality equation directly into the ng-hide directive. Ex:  `ng-hide="country.detail <= 5"`

Comment: @m.e.conroy - thanks for that... But what i am saying is that country.detail doesnt only display a number, e.g. 5.. but this string "5 details available"...

Comment: @OamPsy use the length of the array that contains the details then. `ng-hide="country.detaillist.length <= 0"`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="country in countries" >
   <td data-show="#show-{{$index}}">{{country.name}}</td>
   <td>{{country.population}}</td>
   <td>{{country.detail}}</td>
   <td>{{country.currency}}</td>
   <td>{{country.gpd}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat-end class="countries-detail" ng-if="country.detail[0] > 0">
   <td>
       <div id="show-{{$index}}">
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
          <p>countries detail lorem epsum</p>
       </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Does that work for you?